# Ipad app store sample image sizes

Tags: ipad, app-store

I am about to send in my app to apple for testing but I dont know what the sample image sizes are for the images that appear in the app store.

I know that the big icon of your app is 512x512.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from iPhone development web page:
Screen shots for iPad applications

iTunes Connect requires metadata for iPad app submissions to include a screenshot that meets the following criteria:

```
* In at least one of the following pixel dimensions:
      o 1024 x 768
      o 768 x 1024
      o 1004 x 768
      o 748 x 1024
```

Comment: Thank you so much!
Do you know if the images need to be in the program?
If so do they need some designated file name?

Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Never mind, I found the page that you quoted from.
I could not access it normally, but I can through the PDF file version of the page...

Thank you once again!

Comment: From what I know person responsible for uploading screen shots is doing them using real device, and then uploading them to web page.
Unfortunately I don't know details how he is doing that